# how to bind memory stream to asp.net image controls with out using image url

Tags: asp.net

We have a new requirement to show the signature image in result grid for each record. Currently we store the signature image as base64 format in our database .we are able to convert base 64 to memory stream.
We want to understand does any of your image control support to bind image from memory stream instead of Url .

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show image from server in json data as the <image> tag ?

Comment: no i have to bind that memory stream to <asp:imagecontrol> tag

Comment: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image

Comment: thank you for giving base 64 to bmp converter link but i don't need that converter link . i am getting base 64 value of image from  data base , i would like to convert it to image by using asp.net image controls  that too without using image url property in asp image control tag

Answer (score 0):

You could keep images as base64 string form, and use data url.
The following is a example.

```
   <asp:Image runat="server" ID="myImage" />
```

The code behind is

```cs
    this.myImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
```

The premise is that you need to know all the MIME type of images.

Reference: [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it this way.

A gridview, listview, repeater control - they can all do this.

So markup for a grid view:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Animal" HeaderText="Animal" ItemStyle-Width="200px"/>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                            Height="128px" Width="128px"
                            src='<%# "Data:Image/png;base64," + Eval("Image") %>' 
                         />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And the code to load up the gridview would be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack == false)
        LoadGrid();
}

public void LoadGrid()
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT Animal, Image from tblAnimals",
                               new SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Now I used a direct eval expression - but you  could also use the ItemDataBound event of the gridview (or list view).

Also, I did hard code the "mine" type in above (assumed .png). You often might want to consider to save the file/mine type as a extra column in the database. But, if the picture types are to be all the same types - then a hard code right in the expression as per above will work fine.

If you have a lot of columns for this grid, then I tend to switch over to listview, since each column does NOT need a template, and I find for quick and dirty - grid view is ok, but listview is better for tweaking and lots of customizing. The trick is to get Visual Studio to generate the template + markup, and then blow out all templates except for item template. When you do this, then the crazy truckload of markup is reduced down to "easy" levels. And you can then with greater ease drop in controls - and you don't have template them.

So, the same listview for above would be this:

```
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">

                    <td><asp:Label ID="AnimalLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Animal") %>' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="ImageT1" runat="server" 
                            Height="128px" Width="128px"
                            src='<%# "Data:Image/png;base64," + Eval("Image") %>' 
                         />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                    <tr runat="server" style="">
                        <th runat="server" width="200">Animal</th>
                        <th runat="server">Image</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

So there is somewhat "more" markup, but you can with much greater ease drop in asp.net controls - and you don't have add a templatefield - (about 4 extra lines of markup for every column - so in the long run, I like the listview.

it looks quite much the same, like this:

[image]

And the behind code would be 100% the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vs2022 .net 472. It is simple:

```
Myimage.imageurl = "Data:Image;base64,"+ Base64string
```